# Immediately calling function expression

Tags: javascript, function

How in the world these 2 functions are not same ?

```
var f2 = function () {
    console.log(f2); // undefined --> how and why ?
}();
```

**&**

```
var f1 = function () {
    console.log(f1); // f1 function object
};
f1();
```

Why first one logs `undefined` ? 
I expected same outcome as second one and then I was knocked out of the chair with `undefined` logged.

Comment: A variable is not yet defined while you're defining it.

Comment: in first case when you call function `f2` is not assinged variable, in second - variable have value - anonymous function

Comment: Ah I see now. I need named function expression.

Comment: @BlagoEreš Yup, Its better to go with named functions if you are not going to use them immediately and need to use it more than once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, assignment to `f2` hasn't happened yet. In an assignment expression, the right hand side expression will be evaluated first and the result will be assigned to the left hand side expression. Till then the variable will have the default value `undefined` only.

Applying it in your case, only the result of executing the function object

```
function() {
   console.log(f2);
}
```

will be assigned to `f2`. But then you are accessing `f2` within the anonymous function object. So, the default value `undefined` is returned, since **nothing has been assigned to `f2` yet**.

You can confirm that, like this

```
var f2 = function () {
    return 1;
}();

console.log(f2);
// 1
```

Here, the function object is executed and the result is assigned to `f2`. Till the assignment happens, the value of `f2` will be `undefined` only.

---

**Note:**

In the first case, even after the assignment, if you do `console.log(f2)`, it will log `undefined` only. Because, you are not explicitly returning anything from the function object. So, the default value `undefined` will be returned and that will be stored in `f2`.

---

In the second case, the function object is assigned to `f1` and that is why you are able to invoke it like a function (`f1()`). So, when you log `f1` within `f1` itself, it prints the function object.

Comment: you need add `var f2;` above first case

Comment: @Grundy I meant to say, the result of the function execution will be assigned to `f2`, in the OP's expression. I explained that in words :-)

Comment: I just thought, that you mean equivalent code, instead a part of OP code :-)